# How to fetch json value from web api using ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-web-api, c#-3.0

This may be dumb question but am struggling with this i cannot fetch the value from web api using ajax, let me explain my problem in detail i have created simple web api by using ajax i need to fetch the value how can i achieve this let me post my code what i have tried so far:

Webapi code:

```
  [EnableCors(origins: "http://localhost:8080", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("~/api/getail/{id}/{criteriaid}")]
        public IHttpActionResult GetIncidentByResourceID(int id, int criteriaid)
        {
            IncidentDisplayApiModelCollection collection = objIncidentApiManager.GetDisplayList(id, criteriaid, 4);
            return Json(collection);
        }
```

This is sample ajax request:

```
   <script src="js/jquery-3.2.0.min.js"></script>
              <script >
       $(document).ready(function(){
       $.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:8080/sf/api/getail/1848/29",
    dataType: "json",
     success: function( response ) {
        console.log( response ); // server response
    },
    error: function( response ) {
        console.log( response ); // server response
    }
});

});
       </script>
```

what am getting in firefox console is :

```
Object { readyState: 0, getResponseHeader: .ajax/y.getResponseHeader(), getAllResponseHeaders: .ajax/y.getAllResponseHeaders(), setRequestHeader: .ajax/y.setRequestHeader(), overrideMimeType: .ajax/y.overrideMimeType(), statusCode: .ajax/y.statusCode(), abort: .ajax/y.abort(), state: .Deferred/e.state(), always: .Deferred/e.always(), catch: .Deferred/e.catch(), 9 more… }  index.html:59:9

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8080/sf/api/getail/1848/29. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).
```

I have downloaded cors in nuget manager and added confi.enablecors(); in webapi config.  can someone help me how to resolve this thanks in advance!!

Comment: before marking it as duplicate i have explained i have tried all the methods from that question but still not working

Comment: In which domain (IP address), your ajax code is hosted?

Comment: not ip its just from file

Comment: CORS issue occurs in case of source address and destination address are different. You must be testing this ajax request on some url say : http://localhost:3000

Comment: what i gave is correct ip address

Comment: so you mean IP address for web API is also http://localhost:8080/ and ajax is also http://localhost:8080/ ??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139455/discussion-between-m-yogeshwaran-and-jayakrishnan-gounder).

Comment: ajax is html file from html file :file:///D:/Cordova%20Workshops/ServiceFirst/www/index.html like this is my html url from here am trying to connect web api which is in localhost:8080

Comment: You need to understand CORS properly.
Refer : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

Answer (score 0):

The `origins` parameter should contain the value of the `Origin` request header.

When request is made from page with `file://` URI, browsers set the `Origin` header to be `null` (string) (I've tested in Firefox and Chrome).

So, try to add "null" to the `origins` parameter:

```
    [EnableCors(origins: "null", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
```

but i'm not sure this will work (such an unusual value!)

Or, simpler, just set it to be "*" to allow requests from any origins:

```
    [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
```

NOTE: (!) When deploying to production, **consider carefully** before allowing requests from any origin. It means that literally any website can make AJAX calls to your web API.

Hope it helps